# "There was a problem communicating with Google servers" during AVD configuration

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, ms-android-emulator

This is my first post, so I apologize in advance if somehow it does not adhere to stackoverflow's standards.

I have just created a "Hello World" Xamarin.Forms project (for Android and iOS) using VS 2019 and I am having some issues regarding Android Emulator.

When I create a new AVD and launch it for the first time, it tries to setup "Android SDK built for x86" at the virtual device. Problem is: the process stucks in the middle saying that the device couldn't sign in because there was a problem communicating with Google servers.

Has anyone experienced similar situation and found a fix? I have already tried clearing the cache of all processes and apps involved in the process with no luck.

My virtual device configuration:

- Base device: Nexus 5X
- Processor: x86
- OS: Android Pie 9.0 - API 28

Comment: Did you make an emulator with Google Services? Try to make another one without it (if you don't really need them)

Comment: Good idea, I will try. But in the future I will need access to the map API, can you tell me if it requires Google Services in order to work?